# EF navigation property doesn't seem to update when I change Id

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have the following classes:

```
public class Person {
   public int Id {get; set;}
   ...
   public ICollection<PersonalJobs> Jobs {get; set;}
}

public class PersonalJob {
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public int PersonId {get; set;}
   public int JobId {get; set;}
   public Job Job {get; set;}
   public DateTime StartDate {get; set;}
   ...
}

public class Job {
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Description {get; set;}
   ...
}
```

Now I do something like the following:

```
var _personId = 1;
var _jobId = 15;

_context.Set<Jobs>().Load();  //Pre-Load all jobs

var _person = _context.Persons.Include(p => p.Jobs.Select(j => j.Job))
   .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == _personId);

var _job = _person.Jobs.SingleOrDefault(p => p.JobId == _jobId);
_job.JobId = 23;  //Change the job that this person is tied to.

// At this point, if I try to access _job.Job.Description, it still references the old job.
```

Because the context already had Jobs loaded, I assumed that EF would update the navigation property of _job when I change the ID.  However, this is not the case.  In this case _job.Job still references the job associated with the original Id (15).

Am I wrong in my assumption of how EF handles navigation properties or am I just missing a piece in this puzzle?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to switch what job this guy has?

Comment: which approach are you using to build your db tables? I mean, Codefirst or Model first?? But , in either case , EF will generate an error about the Entity  key...

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to change the job this guy has.  I then need to do validation but my validation needs to access some properties of the job itself.  I want the validation to take place BEFORE I persist anything to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `SaveChanges()` to persist to the database:

```
_job.JobId = 23;

_context.SaveChanges();

// _job.Job now points to Job 23
```

This only works because Job 23 is already loaded into your `DbContext`.

If an object is loaded, EF will hook up your property when you call `SaveChanges()`

---

**EDIT:**

You've loaded all the Jobs, so you could just set the property yourself:

```
_job.Job = _context.Set<Jobs>().Find( 23 );
```

This won't result in any database calls - it will be satisfied from your `DbContext`

It will result in the same `UPDATE` statement when you do call `SaveChanges()`

Comment: As you see in my comment above, I need to reference the new job before persisting changes to the database.  Is there any way to get EF to hook up the property without calling SaveChanges()?

Comment: This is basically what I was doing ... just didn't understand that SaveChanges() or (based on Gert's answer DetectChanges()) was required to make that update.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I just read in your comment you want the reference to be in sync with the new id *before saving*. But that is something that EF does not do automatically. It happens when you call `SaveChanges` allright, but if you want it to happen before that you have to call

```
_context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
```

(Assuming that you use the `DbContext` API)

`DetectChanges` triggers *relationship fixup* which is a process that synchronizes all properties involved in foreign keys.

BTW: you don't have to preload the jobs for this to succeed.

Comment: Thanks Gert.  I do like the simplicity of DetectChanges() ... that would come in handy if I made changes to a number of entities and wanted all the nav properties to get updated rather than having to perform .Find() on each one.  I'll keep this in mind